# Is there a way in salesforce using soql where we can get documents owned by other users but not necessarily shared to me?

Tags: files, contentdocument, system-admin, accesstoken, files-connect

I want to collect all the documents owned by each User in Salesforce account.

I have created accessToken with User A's email, where User A is a System Admin with property PermissionsModifyAllData and PermissionsViewAllData is true.

For User A we get all docs for which he is owner of but for all other users we get docs in which User A is a shared permisison by directly shared or with Domain shared i.e. when trying to query docs for let say User B we are not able to get docs in which User B is owner but it is not shared with User A.

I am using below SOQL with accessToken created with User A's login.

```
https://testdomain.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/queryAll?q=select Id, Title, Description, ContentSize, isDeleted, OwnerId, ParentId, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, CreatedDate, FileType, FileExtension, PublishStatus from ContentDocument where OwnerId = '005XXXX000XXXX00XX'
```

Any lead to solve this usecase will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By Adding QueryAllFiles Permisison to the Profile which User belongs to I am able to fetch all other user's documents as well.
It was mentioned in the salesforce document as well which I missed at the first time.

> Enable the Query All Files permission to let your View All Data users
> bypass the restrictions on querying files. Query All Files returns all
> files, including files in non-member libraries and files in unlisted
> groups. Users can’t edit, upload new versions, or delete files they
> don’t have access to. View All Data permission is required to enable
> Query All Files.